# How to read modal logic's countermodels?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I'm new to Modal Logic and currently playing a tree proof generator just to see how some stuff work, but I can't read the countermodels that the algorithm gives me when my proposition is invalid. I (kinda) understand the concept of possible words and so on, I just can't read it there. Can someone explain me?

Example: [https://www.umsu.de/trees/#%E2%96%A1(a%E2%86%92b)%20|=%20%C2%AC%E2%97%87(a%E2%86%92%C2%ACb)](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#%E2%96%A1(a%E2%86%92b)%20%7C=%20%C2%AC%E2%97%87(a%E2%86%92%C2%ACb))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says that the set of all possible worlds has a singleton element (w) and in that world if we take V(a) and v(b) as false [or, in other words, Vw(a)=F Vw(b)=F; this just says that a and b are both false in w] we get (□(a→b))to be true and (¬◇(a→¬b)) to be false. simply put, it says its not valid because validity is defined as: if everything to left of (|=) is true, then everything to its right MUST be true. However, in this case, given W={w}; Vw(a)=F and Vw(b)=F we get Vw(□(a→b))=T and Vw(¬◇(a→¬b))=F.